# What's the definition of the default error handler?

Tags: php

I'd like to make a slight modification to PHP's default handling of errors (inc. true errors, warnings, notices etc.) but otherwise retain the behaviour exactly, including the message format.

So, I'll need the definition of the default error handler, to modify.

Where can I find it?

Comment: do you mean `throw new Exception('some message');` ? See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for information.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool handler ( int $errno , string $errstr [, string $errfile [, int $errline [, array $errcontext ]]] )
```

You can find the definition of the error handler in the PHP manual for set_error_handler(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: I see nothing that page identifies that or anything as the definition of the DEFAULT error handler. Can you tell me where you see it?